# A component is not receiving any of it's @Input values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I use Angular 8 and I have 3 components:

- CalculationFirst : app-calculation-first
- CalculationSecond : app-calculation-second
- CalculationThird : app-calculation-third

CalculationFirst is the "parent" component and has CalculationSecond as a "child" in a way that I use CalculationSecond inside html template of CalculationFirst.

So in CalculationFirst.component.html it looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate *ngIf="settings.isloaded == true">
    <div class="row">
        <app-calculation-second [elements]="settings.seconds.elements" [epics]="epics"[types]="types" (opendialoglistevent)="openDialogList($event)"></app-calculation-second>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then CalculationSecond.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row content" *ngFor="let element of elements;">
      <div class="col-lg-14">
        <app-calculation-third [elem]="element" [types]="types"></app-calculation-third>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally CalculationThird.component.html looks like :

```
<div class="col-lg-14">
  TEST_TEXT_1
  {{elem}}
  TEST_TEXT_2
</div>
```

Now, the problem is if I were to just look at my rendered page, only TEST_TEXT_1 page shows, {{elem}} does not render and neither does TEST_TEXT_2. If I am to check the value of elem, it is undefined. I would expect to get an error that I am trying to display undefined, however I do not get anything. My environment.ts is not set to production, so I do not know if my error is not big enough for angular to inform me. (On a tangent, I don't even get an error if I use a json object in an *ngFor instead of an enumerable (Array), but I'm still not sure if I have some lacking setting).

I have also tried, when I use the third component, to not pass the element from *ngFor but to pass a handmade object {'elemId':0}, this had the same result.

If I move :

```
<app-calculation-third [elem]="element" [types]="types"></app-calculation-third>
```

to CalculationFirst, making it a direct child, it works perfectly fine, regardless of what I put in there. Is there a limit to the amount of child components you can have? Am I missing something?

*Edit: Also for those who suggested it is the *ngFor or the usage of different variables, I can make CalculationSecond look like the following and still it doesn't work:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row content" *ngFor="let element of elements;">
      <div class="col-lg-14">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <app-calculation-third [elem]="{ elementId: '' }" [types]="types"></app-calculation-third>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the elements to `seconds` input.

```
[seconds]="settings.seconds.elements"
```

But you use `elements` in your `app-second-calculation` element.

Comment: sorry that is not a problem, I forgot to mention I rename the variables. My bad. seconds becomes elements. Even more so, even if I take out the <app-calculation-third> out of the ng-for and just put it in CalculationSecond anywhere and pass a hang-written object, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've renamed seconds to elements for clarity